# USB CDC based on STM32F103 has different transmission effect on Windows7 and Ubuntu

Tags: usb, stm32, cdc

I used STM32F103 to send data to the PC via USB CDC at a frequency of 4000Hz, 21 bytes per packet. The code generated by STMCube. And then I found that only 1000 packets can be received per second on Windows7 via serial assistant, but it can normally receive 4000 packets per second on Ubuntu via CuteCOM. How do I achieve the same effect on Windows7? Thank you.

```
int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();
    while(1)
    {
        __WFI();
    }
}

void HAL_SYSTICK_Callback(void)      //4000Hz
{
    CDC_Transmit_FS(buff, 21);
}
```

I use python to test, and the result is:
[image: Windows7]

[image: Ubuntu]

Comment: very interesting - but the FS hardware tick is 1ms.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. CDC belongs to bulk transmission, is bulk transmission also limited by 1ms? If it is 1ms, and the USB_FS_MAX_PACKET_SIZE is 64 bytes, how can I make the transmission speed close to the max speed - 12Mbit/s? And is there no way to send 4,000 packets to Windows7 per second? Thank you.